# How can I make these jquery flexboxes responsive and fit inside the jumbotron despite screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I want the jquery flexboxes to be responsive the same way an image is. 
Currently when I resize the window the flexboxes don't shrink to fit inside the grey pic I have as a background image for the jumbotron. The boxes stretch past the image and create white space.

I'm trying to get the flexboxes to shrink or even rearrange themselves so they can fit on small screens and stay in alignment with the jumbotron.

i guess the simplest solution would be to get the background image to expand with the boxes.

I'm making this on code pen so here is a link:      https://codepen.io/blkgurlcode/pen/qqJzYX

```
 <!-- Begin pg 2 -->
  <div class="jumbotron gap img-fluid" id="bend">
<!-- Flex Boxes -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8 flex">
        <a bg="a" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:250px;height:125px;" width="325" height="175">A</a>
    <a bg="b" style="left:260px;height:100px;top:0px;width:125px;" width="250" height="175">B</a>
    <a bg="c" style="left:395px;height:250px;top:0px;width:75px;" width="125" height="350">C</a>
    <a bg="d" style="left:480px;height:75px;top:0px;width:75px;" width="175" height="150">D</a>
    <a bg="e" style="left:565px;height:125px;top:0px;width:200px;" width="200" height="250">E</a>
    <a bg="f" style="left:480px;height:200px;top:85px;width:75px;" width="150" height="225">F</a>
    <a bg="g" style="left:0px;height:100px;top:135px;width:75px;" width="305" height="150">G</a>
    <a bg="h" style="left:260px;height:75px;top:110px;width:125px;" width="200" height="200">H</a>
    <a bg="i" style="left:85px;height:140px;top:135px;width:165px;" width="200" height="140">I</a>
    <a bg="j" style="left:565px;height:150px;top:135px;width:75px;" width="125" height="275">J</a>
    <a bg="k" style="left:650px;height:75px;top:135px;width:75px;" width="75" height="200">K</a>
      </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-box">
     <p>Portfolio</p>
      </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
 /* Page 2 */
#bend {
background-size: cover;
background-image:  url("http://i68.tinypic.com/jfupsz.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
padding: 0px;
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 800px;
}

/*flex boxes */
.flex {position:relative; max-width:850px;min-height:300px;margin-top:150px;margin-left:80px;padding:0px;}

    .flex a {background-color:white;display:block;width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:8px;position:absolute;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;cursor:pointer;text-align:left;text-shadow:1px 1px 20px #000;color:white;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;text-indent:10px;line-height:30px;}
    [bg=a] {background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7013/6448917381_0b754e86fb_z.jpg);}
    [bg=b] {background-image:url(http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8156/7362866426_bf285ebd45.jpg);background-size:300px auto;}
    [bg=c] {background-image:url(http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5117/7410370290_0935419fc3.jpg);}
    [bg=d] {background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7262/7419245080_bb752ed1d6.jpg);}
    [bg=e] {background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7003/6468321069_3375be3073_z.jpg);background-size:auto 280px;}
    [bg=f] {background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7220/7342556872_46cddaf9b0.jpg);background-size:auto 280px;}
    [bg=g] {background-image:url(http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8021/7322604950_348c535903.jpg);background-size:auto 200px;}
    [bg=h] {background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7076/7286717012_6e6b450243.jpg);}
    [bg=i] {background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7129/7452167788_a3f6aa3104.jpg);background-size:auto 200px;}
    [bg=j] {background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7153/6480022425_a8d419e663_z.jpg);background-size:auto 280px;}
    [bg=k] {background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7225/7269592732_c4b7918626.jpg);background-size:auto 280px;}

div p{

}

/* pg 2 txt */
p {
  text-align:center;
  margin-top: 200px;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #021a40;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited the question and added more code

Comment: Hi, I am confused on your question. When you say "JQuery Flexbox" do you just mean Flexbox? (I dont see any JQuery code used). The code in your codepen differs from the code posted here so I am not sure which version you are using. Also natively images are not normally responsive, i think that's just a by product of using Bootstrap. I dont see where the A-K HREF links are being used in your codepen.